# How can Joe can bring things to Heaven?

Tags: soul-2020

In *Soul* (2020), here is a picture of Joe wearing glasses:

[image]

In the zone, using a small maple seed 22 had kept, Joe convinces her that
she is ready to live, returning her to normal:

[image]

How was he able to bring his glasses and the maple seed into Heaven with him?

Comment: Are these actual things, or just projections?  You might as well ask why he has eyes, no?

Comment: He has a cool hat too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Those items are part of the way he sees himself.** He is an adult who has had time to develop habits and form a complex self-image. Same for the other souls he meets on the conveyor belt to the light - who all look different, and some of whom are also wearing hats.  The pre-born souls are much simpler in their appearance because they haven't lived a life yet.

[image]

[image]